# Get model from m:n relationship

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I've got a problem on a SQL Query to model logic.
Here are my tables i'vev created for this project.

At First my Product Table

```
public partial class Products
{
    public Products()
    {
        this.Orders_Products = new HashSet<Orders_Products>();
        this.ShoppingCarts_Products = new HashSet<ShoppingCarts_Products>();
    }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public int PPB { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Categories Categories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Orders_Products> Orders_Products { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ShoppingCarts_Products> ShoppingCarts_Products { get; set; }
}
```

Then the ShoppingCart Table

```
public partial class ShoppingCarts
{
    public ShoppingCarts()
    {
        this.ShoppingCarts_Products = new HashSet<ShoppingCarts_Products>();
    }

    public int ShoppingCartId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public virtual AspNetUsers AspNetUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ShoppingCarts_Products> ShoppingCarts_Products { get; set; }
}
```

And at least the Connection Table between

```
public partial class ShoppingCarts_Products
{
    public int ShoppingCartId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }

    public virtual Products Products { get; set; }
    public virtual ShoppingCarts ShoppingCarts { get; set; }
}
```

Now i need to get a list of all the Products in my own ShoppingCart.
What kind of model should i create?

I thin k i need to write an sql statement, which includes both of the maintables and merge them with the connection table.
But i can't fnd any samle at the internet.
Does anybody know a sample or can give me a hint, how to solve that problem?

After this step i need to show that view on the layout site.

Okay, i will try to write the query with the LINQ to SQL Format. Now i try to show this View as a Partial View on my Layoutside.

```
@Html.Partial("_ShoppingCartPartial", Html.Action("MyShoppingCart","ShoppingCarts"))   

 // GET: MyShoppingCart
    public List<ShoppingCarts_Products> MyShoppingCart()
    {

        List<ShoppingCarts_Products> myproducts = db.ShoppingCarts_Products.Where(i => i.ShoppingCartId == 1).ToList();            

        return myproducts;
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
select * from ShoppingCarts_Products
where ShoppingCarts_Products.ShoppingCartId = <variable>
left join ShoppingCarts on ShoppingCarts.ShoppingCartId = ShoppingCarts_Products.ShoppingCartId 
left join Products on ShoppingCarts.ProductId  = Products.ProductId
```

Also, expand the field selection criteria to select only the fields you need.